# UK Visa Refusal Letter, email or attached with passport?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

Dears,

I have applied for UK visitor visa, this is my second attempt. my first one was refused. HO sent me the refusal letter in an email and I received my passport later. But this time they sent me an email stating the visa application has been concluded and has been sent back to the Visa Application centre. Does this mean I have got the visa, or do they ever send the refusal letter with the passport?

I need this because I have to take the tickets as I have to travel on December 21st if I get the visa. your help is highly appreciated.

I applied in Germany.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton for your response, not really, I know concluded means the decision has been made. but last time, they sent the refusal via email. I would like to know if anyone has been refused without getting an email.

Thanks again

Comment: We can't say. It's a totally generic email that does not reveal whether the application was approved or not. That's why I suggested the linked answer.

Comment: @Ranj What others have received or not received has no bearing on your case. You will have to wait until you get some communication from UK immigration.

Comment: I agree with both of you. Thank you very much @MichaelHampton and #Arthur's Pass

Comment: Just so you know, I got the visa. It is more likely in Germany that refusal letters are sent via emails.